# Can't get external svg element by ID

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg, icons

I have generated an svg spritesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<symbol viewBox="0 0 17.5 14.663" id="img--svg--icon-twitter" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M11.283.153c1.736-.485 3.074.263 3.685 1.151.694-.226 1.372-.47 2.072-.691-.004.841-.538 1.478-.883 1.727.704.166 1.343-.48 1.343-.48-.175.976-1.035 1.746-1.611 1.977-.239 6.592-3.272 10.956-10.382 10.823h-.46c-.422 0-4.29-.45-5.047-1.843 2.341.192 4.011-.412 4.835-1.15-.989-.293-2.761-.464-3.07-2.881.362.105.583.223 1.228.117C1.757 8.067.385 7.366.461 5.218c.294.32 1.1.523 1.381.461C1.117 5.444-.188 2.398.921.843 2.794 2.654 4.769 4.364 8.29 4.528 8.506 2.288 9.461.787 11.283.153z"/></symbol>
</svg>
```

I have saved it as sprite.svg into img directory. Then I want to get svg element from sprite with use tag by ID :

```
 <ul class="social__list">
          <li class="social__item">
            <a class="social__link social__link--twitter" href="#">
           <svg class="social__link social__link--twitter_icon" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#img--svg--icon-twitter"></use>
           </svg>
          </a></li>
          <li class="social__item"><a class="social__link--facebook" href="#">Фейсбук</a></li>
          <li class="social__item"><a class="social__link--youtube" href="#">Ютуб</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The icon shows in firefox but doesn't shows in chrome at all. My chrome version is 61.0.3163.100. I have tried to turn off all chrome expansion and open page in private mode - it still doesn't shows. What can cause the problem ?
[image: Screen with this svg bug]

Comment: You tagged it for Chrome specifically. Does that mean it works on other browsers?

Comment: Works only in firefox but it strange for me that it is a chrome problem

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, how can I make external svg file in code snippet and make it work?

Comment: Codepen lets you do that.